# Transpose multiple columns as rows - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a lot of data that needs to be migrated to a new table. However, the table structure as changed.

So my problem is, I need to construct a MySQL query, or SProc, that will achieve the following:

I currently have the data set as follows:

```
uuid                                    level0     level1     level2 

FFC28DA7-9753-4D83-BAFF-A3623EAF6545    Insurance           
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    Profile    Age_Group    25-34   
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    Profile    Gender         M 
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    Profile    State         NSW    
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    Profile    Country        AU    
821B10BC-EED7-4E72-A77D-5119A2C28331    Profile    Age_Group    25-34   
821B10BC-EED7-4E72-A77D-5119A2C28331    Profile     Gender        M 
FFC28DA7-9753-4D83-BAFF-A3623EAF6545    Insurance   Health
```

There are a lot of records as such.

However now, the data needs to be migrated into a new table, therefore looking at the above data set, needs to be like this

```
uuid                                    taxid_n     

FFC28DA7-9753-4D83-BAFF-A3623EAF6545    Insurance   
FFC28DA7-9753-4D83-BAFF-A3623EAF6545    Health
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    Profile
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    Age_Group
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    25-34
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    Gender
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    M
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    State
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    NSW
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    Country
2A772655-E580-40BC-B08F-4D279AEEEC74    AU
821B10BC-EED7-4E72-A77D-5119A2C28331    Profile
821B10BC-EED7-4E72-A77D-5119A2C28331    Age_Group
821B10BC-EED7-4E72-A77D-5119A2C28331    25-34
821B10BC-EED7-4E72-A77D-5119A2C28331    Gender
821B10BC-EED7-4E72-A77D-5119A2C28331    M
```

So basically, each level will be a new row, plus the parent level, level0, will not be repeated. That is Profile > Gender > Male and Profile > Kids > Gender > Male, will have 6 records, and not 7, by the uuid. The uuids will be unique.

Note: There are 6 levels that is level0 - level5, so the query or SProc should accommodate it.

The query to get the raw data would be:

```
 SELECT 
uuid,
level0,    level1,
level2,    level3,
level4,    level5,
level6,    pubid,
siteid,    ipaddress,
dt,    status,
created, now ()
FROM
segmentdata
WHERE
status = 1
```

Any help with this, will be great!

Thanks

Comment: Rows in MySQL represent unordered sets, so how will you know which key is paired with which value?

Comment: It would be from the dt column. That is if dt = 1, than my code will know its profile info and so forth.

Comment: But there is no `dt` in your result.

Comment: I didnt really include it. The result data set would be, uuid, taxid_n, pubid, siteid, ipaddres, dt, status, created, modified.

Comment: Well, if someone manages to answer this based upon the information provided in the question, hats off to them

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `union`

```
select uid, level0 as level from segmentdata
union
select uid, level1 from segmentdata
union
select uid, level2 from segmentdata
union
select uid, level3 from segmentdata
union
select uid, level4 from segmentdata
union
select uid, level5 from segmentdata;
```

`union` will get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: This way, I will get 6 profiles, if I have 6 profiled levels. I need level0 once only, and the appending columns after it